# Capturing Traffic of Router

Tags: linux, wireshark, router

My machine is connected to a wireless router. Is it possible to analyse packets coming and going to the router? Can I use the bridged mode for achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "[WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org/)"

Refer the below link for more info:

https://superuser.com/questions/453059/how-can-i-capture-packets-going-from-my-router-to-a-specific-server